# Centering image with JQuery after image source is set on document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a question that I think is regarding the syncing of functions in an HTML/JQuery usage:

I have a simple html file, e.g.

```
<div id="wrapperA" style="top: 50%">
    <span id="wordfortargetpic1"></span>
    <span id="wordfortargetpic2"></span>
    <span id="wordfortargetpic3"></span>
    <img id="pic1" class="imgdiv" src="" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

to which I add the `src` attribute with JQuery:

`$("#pic1").attr("src", "mysource.png");`

CSS for `.imgdiv`:

```
.imgdiv{
  max-width: 120px;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Now since the size if my image can vary, I wrote a JQuery function that centers elements by taking their dimensions and adjusting the margins:

```
function css_center(object) {
  object.css({
    "margin-left": -($(object).width() / 2),
    "margin-top": -($(object).height() / 2)
  });
}
```

My problem now is that if I run my script with

1. setting the `src`
2. centering the `img`

it does not work (i.e. it does not center the image). 
It does work however, if I run the css_center function in the console.

I suspect that this is to do with how the functions are run and I am missing a part on this.

To address this, I tried to circumvent this by building a function that only sets the src called `getImage()` and call that function with a callback that centers the image like:

```
getImage(function(){
  css_center($(".imgdiv"));    
})
```

doesn't work either. What am I missing here?

Comment: Why don't you center the image using pure css? That way it doesn't matter what size the image is, it will always be centered.

Comment: @MeisamMulla How would I do that if I do not know the width and height of it without writing css centering for each image? I want it to be as generic as possible.

Comment: @ben_aaron Just write the CSS for the `imgdiv` class.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I've added the css which I hope clarifies my problem. I do never know which image is displayed nor do I know the image height or width.

Comment: Attach your centering function to `onload` event on `#pic1`. So your function only runs after the image is loaded, getting the correct dimensions

Comment: Working fine here - http://jsfiddle.net/mpcpzvvp/

Comment: @rzr Yours does the trick. I was not aware that this is what I should have been looking for. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your function runs after the image has been loaded

```
$('#pic1').on('load', function(){
    this.style.marginTop = -(this.height/2) + 'px';
    this.style.marginLeft = -(this.width/2) + 'px';
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two divs, one for horiz alignment, one for vert alignment like this:

```
div.horizontal {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

div.vertical {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

<div class="horizontal" id="wrapperA" style="top: 50%">
    <div class="vertical">
        <span id="wordfortargetpic1"></span>
        <span id="wordfortargetpic2"></span>
        <span id="wordfortargetpic3"></span>
        <img id="pic1" class="imgdiv" src="" />
    </div>
</div>
```